# ffmpeg black screen, sound working fine

Tags: php, ffmpeg, flv, video-encoding, mp4

When converting an .flv file to .mp4 i used this command:

ffmpeg -i y.mp4.flv -ar 22050 y.mp4

Sound is fine but i have no image (not in web player & not when downloaded to pc)
. FFmpeg is working fine when i'm grabbing some screens from .mp4 for "preview.jpg" files.
So am I missing some kind of codec?
(First time i'm converting video without commercial software... )

Also i'd like to ask if the is a more efficient way to detect file type then:

```
$video = file_get_contents("www.remotefile.com/1.mp4");
if (strpos($video, "flv") !== 0){// FLV, fLV etc
  file_put_contents($path."1.flv", $video);
  //further processing 
}
```

Edit: im using Debian Lenny as OS

Answer (score 1):

Your black screen problem can only be solved by looking at the output of the ffmpeg command. If it can't detect a codec, it will say so. If you are using ffmpeg from Debian, it's likely to miss support for some formats.

```
 Stream #0.1: Video: unknown   // or something like that
```

(Your URLs are wrong. It needs a http:// prefix). Detecting the video type is achieved best by reading out the HTTP [response header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) `Content-Type`. But that would be easier when using a HTTP library instead of file_get_contents.

If you want to rely on file extensions, then use this for simplicity:

```
if (strrchr($url, ".") == ".flv") {
```

Or a switch statement.

Comment: Thanks, it outputs this: Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 360x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 464 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc

flv and mp4 files always consist somewhere in the file things like mp4, flv, FLV etc, i have made some if statements checking that.
Thanks the the http header link, i will look into that.

Comment: Here full ffmpeg dump: http://pastebin.com/2ZwacfcN

Comment: That looks alright. I can't see a problem with it. Maybe you should just try another version; there might still be a bug in your binary/release. But also try encoding it into a simpler format (e.g. mpeg) for testing

Comment: I've deleted it all and reinstalled everything using this guide:http://www.alfersoft.com.ar/blog/2010/11/01/building-ffmpeg-in-debian-lenny/ but now ffmpeg doesnt start anymore

ffmpeg --help
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Here dump from: ldd `which ffmpeg`
http://pastebin.com/zy8bMcrT

Comment: Oh my, compiling by hand. Search for a statically linked ffmpeg rather. If all else fails, try to install the Ubuntu version (and dependencies!).